# Two-factor authentication setting for all users in G Suite

Tags: google-admin-sdk

How can we check to see if 2-factor authentication is enabled for all users, and if not, how can it be enabled for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since recently there are 2 new fields isEnforcedIn2Sv, isEnrolledIn2Sv (both read-only) returned in the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) users.list() / get().

This one should be more accurate due to the big delay in UserUsageReport.

Answer (score 0):

To check programmatically: The [`is_2sv_enrolled`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts) property of a user account's [`UserUsageReport`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get) will be true if the user has 2FA turned on.

To turn on for a user: You CANNOT turn it on programmatically for a user. A user needs to do this themselves.

Best practice for a large domain is to turn on [`Enforcement`](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2548882?hl=en) for 2-Step Verification. This can be done org unit by org unit and on a timeline with a deadline (that you can move) and allows exception groups. Users will gradually be provoked to enroll with interstitial prompt flows during login.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!